# How do I align different size images

Tags: php, html, css, image, alignment

I'm trying to write a page with different size images but can't figure out how to align them properly.
This is how the web-page looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcGuj.jpg

I have added bootstrap img-fluid for responsiveness. If i set fixed height images wont scale down properly on smaller screens.

I cleaned some non related data with '...' just to make code look cleaner. 
My current code:

```
    foreach(row...) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding...">

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body" style="padding...">

          <a href="">
            <div>
              <img class="img-fluid" style="width: 100%;" src="row->image..." alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5> title </h1>
              <h6> date </h6>
            </div>
          </a>

        </div> <!-- /card body -->
      </div> <!-- /card -->

    </div> <!-- /col-6 -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm hoping that images will scale down on smaller screens.

Comment: Try min-height to image

Comment: This is a php code. Please add the PHP tag

Comment: @MMJM altought the code in the question is a php chunk the question has nothinng to do with php.

Answer (score 1):

**TL:DR** `object-fit: cover;` will do the trick.

**Solution 1 - FIXED HEIGHT**

with this solution you have to set  value for the height of the images: the photos won't stretch but the ratio will be different for each screen

```
.img-fluid {
   height: 200px; /* insert here your desired height*/
   object-fit:cover;
}
```

**Solution 2 - REAL FLUID**

this solution is a little trickier but the photos will have always the ratio you will choose.

```
.card-body a div:first-child {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   padding-top: 60%; /*insert value for the desired ratio. ie: 60% -> 10/6 image*/ 
}

.img-fluid {
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```css
.img-card img{width:100%;height:300px;object-fit:cover;}
.img-card{margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:15px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="img-card">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VDNd4KjELkU/maxresdefault.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-6">
    <div class="img-card">
      <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0f/5e/fc/f5/inkaya-cinari.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-6">
    <div class="img-card">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/scenery-5680647.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-6">
    <div class="img-card">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/11/03/47/evening-1038148__340.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```